# How to fix pagination with category and subcategory filter?

Tags: javascript

This is my Js for checkbox filters for subcategory and category when no subcategory is there also when category is selected all of its subcategories are selected. The issue is with pagination when I select any filter only first 20 products are displayed and when next is clicked it shows 0 items and then when i move back from that page first 20 also disapperars. I am using LIMIT clause in php for pagination. Can anyone help resolve me this.

```
    const productList = document.querySelector("#products");
    const productCountElement = document.querySelector("#product-count");
    let currentPage = 1;
    const pageElement = document.querySelector("#page-number");
    const prevPageButton = document.getElementById("prevPage");
    const nextPageButton = document.getElementById("nextPage");
    let totalProducts;

    function updateProductList() {
    const selectedSubcategoryIds = Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll(".subcategory-checkbox:checked")
    ).map((checkbox) =\> checkbox.getAttribute("data-subcategory-id"));

    const url =
    selectedSubcategoryIds.length \> 0
    ? `get_products.php?subcategory_ids=${selectedSubcategoryIds.join(           ","         )}&page=${currentPage}`
    : `get_products.php?page=${currentPage}`;

    fetch(url)
    .then((response) =\> response.json())
    .then((data) =\> {
    totalProducts = data.total_count; // Store the total count in the variable
    renderProducts(data.products);
    const totalPages = totalProducts / 20;
    productCountElement.textContent = totalProducts;
    nextPageButton.disabled = currentPage \> totalPages;

        prevPageButton.disabled = currentPage <= 1;
        
        document
            .querySelectorAll(".subcategory-checkbox")
            .forEach(function (checkbox) {
            checkbox.addEventListener("change", updateProductList);
            });
        });

    }

    prevPageButton.addEventListener("click", () =\> {
    // Handle the "Previous" button click
    if (currentPage \> 1) {
    currentPage--;

        updateProductList();

    }
    });

    nextPageButton.addEventListener("click", () =\> {
    // Handle the "Next" button click

    currentPage++;

    updateProductList();
    });
    // ...

    function renderProducts(products) {
    productList.innerHTML = "";
    let currentRow;
    let counter = 0;
    pageElement.innerHTML = "Page " + currentPage;
    products.forEach((product, index) =\> {
    if (counter % 4 === 0) {
    currentRow = productList.insertRow();
    }

        const cell = currentRow.insertCell();
        cell.style.width = "200px";
        cell.style.marginRight = "10px";
        
        //const image = document.createElement('img');
        //image.src = product.orderimage;
        //image.alt = 'Product Image';
        
        const productInfo = document.createElement("div");
        productInfo.classList.add("product-info");
        
        const idHeading = document.createElement("h3");
        idHeading.textContent = product.id;
        productInfo.appendChild(idHeading);
        
        const fabricHeading = document.createElement("h6");
        fabricHeading.textContent = product.fabric;
        productInfo.appendChild(fabricHeading);
        
        const designNoHeading = document.createElement("h4");
        designNoHeading.textContent = product.design_no;
        productInfo.appendChild(designNoHeading);
        
        // cell.appendChild(image);
        cell.appendChild(productInfo);
        
        counter++;
        
        if (counter === 4) {
        currentRow = productList.insertRow();
        counter = 0;
        }

    });

    productCountElement.textContent = products.length;
    }
    document.querySelectorAll(".subcategory-checkbox").forEach(function (checkbox) {
    checkbox.addEventListener("change", updateProductList);
    });
    updateProductList();

    //product by category

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const productList = document.querySelector("#products");
    const productCountElement = document.querySelector("#product-count");

    function updateProductList() {
    const selectedCategoryIds = Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll(".category-checkbox:checked")
    ).map((checkbox) =\> checkbox.getAttribute("data-category-id"));

        const url =
        selectedCategoryIds.length > 0
            ? `get_product_category.php?category_ids=${selectedCategoryIds.join(
                ","
            )}&page=${currentPage}`
            : `get_product_category.php?page=${currentPage}`;
        
        fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            const totalProducts = data.total_count;
            renderProducts(data.products);
            nextPageButton.disabled = currentPage * 4 >= totalProducts;
            productCountElement.textContent = totalProducts; // Update the product count element
            document
            .querySelectorAll(".category-checkbox")
            .forEach(function (checkbox) {
                checkbox.addEventListener("change", updateProductList);
            });
        });

    }
    // ...

    function renderProducts(products) {
    productList.innerHTML = "";
    let currentRow;
    let counter = 0;

        products.forEach((product, index) => {
        if (counter % 4 === 0) {
            currentRow = productList.insertRow();
        }
        
        const cell = currentRow.insertCell();
        cell.style.width = "200px";
        cell.style.marginRight = "10px";
        
        // const image = document.createElement('img');
        //image.src = product.orderimage;
        //image.alt = 'Product Image';
        
        const productInfo = document.createElement("div");
        productInfo.classList.add("product-info");
        
        const idHeading = document.createElement("h3");
        idHeading.textContent = product.id;
        productInfo.appendChild(idHeading);
        
        const fabricHeading = document.createElement("h6");
        fabricHeading.textContent = product.fabric;
        productInfo.appendChild(fabricHeading);
        
        const designNoHeading = document.createElement("h4");
        designNoHeading.textContent = product.design_no;
        productInfo.appendChild(designNoHeading);
        
        //cell.appendChild(image);
        cell.appendChild(productInfo);
        
        counter++;
        
        if (counter === 4) {
            currentRow = productList.insertRow();
            counter = 0;
        }
        });
        
        productCountElement.textContent = products.length;

    }
    document.querySelectorAll(".category-checkbox").forEach(function (checkbox) {
    checkbox.addEventListener("change", updateProductList);
    });

    updateProductList();
    });
```

I am expecting filters to worrk along with pagination as same when no category is selected

Answer (score 1):

Let the database query do the pagination instead of app code.  For example, the 4th page would be:

```
ORDER BY category, subcategory
OFFSET 60  LIMIT 20
```

This has the desirable (or undesirable?) property of finishing with all the entires for a category (with more than 20 subcategories) before moving to the next category.

If there is inserts/deletions to the list of [sub]categories, there can be glitches where a user sees an item twice or misses an item.  This is a flaw in using `OFFSET` that can be remedied by "remembering where you left off".  See [*Pagination*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination) for a discussion of how.

Comment: I am doing already with query. this limit & offset works fine when not category or subcategory is selected. but for category only first page works and other pages shows 0 items

Comment: @AnsRiaz, what does your query look like in that case?

Comment: Its resolved  issue was with function names